# Display: Inline-block no funciona

Tags: html, css

tengo un problema con CSS, no me funciona display: inline-block, en casi ninguna pagina, cada que intento que sea un elemento en linea sucede esto

```css
* {
      font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
      background-color: #202020;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .nav__bar {
      font-size: 20px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 0;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="nav__bar">
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Showcase</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Acerca</a></li>
             </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS**

Soy algo nuevo en CSS, por lo cual no entiendo que sucede.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás aplicando el `inline-block` al div con la clase `.nav__bar`, de hecho funciona. Pero si lo que quieres es aplicarlo a los `li` entonces debes usar `li` en el selector.

```css
* {
      font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
      background-color: #202020;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .nav__bar li {
      font-size: 20px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 0;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="nav__bar">
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Showcase</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Acerca</a></li>
             </ul>
          </div>
          
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Entonces, ¿Para que funcione correctamente debo añadirlo al selector de abajo?

Comment: Sí, el selector debe especificar que el elemento a modificar es un `li`.